# "1146 - Table 'table' doesn't exist"

Tags: php, database, phpmyadmin

I restarted my computer and then, my tables does not exist anymore.

Bug?

I had two tables.
Actually, they appear inside the database, but when i click it says:

> 1146 - Table 'table' doesn't exist

How can I fix this?

Comment: Did you select the correct database with your PHP?

Comment: did you restart the db server

Comment: Why did you name your table table in the first place?

Comment: What do you mean when you click ? Which database are you using ? Which GUI are you using to open your tables ? Please elaborate and add more details!.   @Scrowler - too good !

Answer (score -1):

I know it's been over 6 years, but I had this same issue. Turned out instead of naming the table, I named the database itself. This was in my insert query.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts. Can you explain more about this?

Comment: I had my query as the following: $sql = 'SELECT' username FROM databasename

it should be: $sql = 'SELECT' username FROM tablename